# XStream deserialize xml having list of hierarchical object

Tags: xml, list, polymorphism, xstream, hierarchical

I have below xml which i want to deserialize in XStream.

```
<comments>
  <B>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Name 1</name>
  </B>
  <C>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>name 2</name>
    <desc>Desc 2</desc>
  </C>
  <B>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>name 3</name>
  </B>
</comments>
```

The object hierarchy is as below

```
@XStreamAlias("comments")
class Comments {
  @XStreamImplicit
  List<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
}

@XStreamAlias("A")
class A {

}

@XStreamAlias("B")
class B extends A {
  long id ;
  String name;
}

@XStreamAlias("C")
class C extends A {
  long id;
  String desc;
  String name;
}
```

The Deserialize code that i have is

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(Boolean.TRUE);
xstream.alias("comments", Comments.class);
String comments= "path to comments xml";
Comments comments = (Comments)xstream.fromXML(new File(path));
```

While running the above, i get the below exception,

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field test.Comments.B
---- Debugging information ----
field               : B
class               : test.Comments
required-type       : test.Comments
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /comments/B
line number         : 2
version             : not available
-------------------------------
at     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.handleUnknownField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:495)
at     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:351)
```

Could anyone pls help me deserialize the above.

It would also be great help if anyone could point out the best place to learn XStream, I have been searching throughout net for any reference material but apart the XStreams homepage, i dont see anyone talk abt advanced topics.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations are meant for serialization, not for de-serialization. You can leave the annotations out and use the following:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("comments", ArrayList.class);
xstream.alias("B", B.class);
xstream.alias("C", C.class);
xstream.alias("A", A.class);
Object o = xstream.fromXML(in);
```

The result will be a list with A, B or C objects depending on the element name.

Comment: "The result will be a list with A, B or C objects depending on the element name"
Does that mean that the result is supposed to be an ArrayList or of type 'Comments'?

Comment: Just answered my own question: it returns an ArrayList.